# Binding to ActualSize

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, binding

For a given Width I want to achieve [image: this]

I'm building this xaml tree:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="CardContentPresenter"
                  Height="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                   ElementName=CardContentPresenter,
                                   Converter={StaticResource WidthToHeightConverter},
                                   Mode=OneWay}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Border x:Name="CardBorder">
        <Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                ElementName=CardBorder,
                                Converter={StaticResource WidthToContentWidthConverter},
                                Mode=OneWay}"
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
                                 ElementName=CardBorder,
                                 Converter={StaticResource WidthToContentWidthConverter},
                                 Mode=OneWay}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="CardContentContentPresenter"
                                  Height="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                                   ElementName=CardContentContentPresenter,
                                                   Converter={StaticResource HeightToWidthConverter},
                                                   Mode=OneWay}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid />
                </ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</ContentPresenter>
```

but as I can see by a breakpoints inside the converters, an order of the Height/Width's calculations is messy (for example, the inner-inner-Height calculates before the inner-Width, so the value is incorrect).

How can I control an order of the properties' calculations? Or the whole my approach is wrong and there is another way to deal with it?